# How i convert array object to specific JSON format using Angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular5

From Material Table i select rows using checkbox and log in console -

```
setTimeout(() => {
        this.selectedRows = this.selection.selected;
        console.log(this.selectedRows);
        });
0: {position: 12, name: "Magnesium", weight: 24.305, symbol: "Mg"}
1: {position: 14, name: "Silicon", weight: 28.0855, symbol: "Si"}
```

How I convert this into using position value

```
"ContactIds":["12","14"]
```

Comment: is your selectedRows has value as ```[ {position: 12, name: "Magnesium", weight: 24.305, symbol: "Mg"},
        {position: 14, name: "Silicon", weight: 28.0855, symbol: "Si"}]``` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new object like this:

```
const positions = { ContactIds : this.selectedRows.map(r => r.position) }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the selections collection, it is now in the @material/cdk

```
import {SelectionModel} from '@angular/cdk/collections';

export class....
selection = new SelectionModel<interface>(true, []);
```

in your html, when selecting a row

```
selection.toggle(row)
```

If you can't use it, let me know and I see if I can make an example in stackblitz.